# RoR Carrierwave: Add remote files with multiple upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using the possibility to upload multiple files at once with carrierwave as described here: 
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

So I have

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :images, ImagesUploader
  serialize :images, JSON
  ...
end
```

Now I want to upload a remote file (not from local drive). Usually I would use something like this in my controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  item.remote_images_url = params[:image_url]
  ...
end
```

But the helper *remote_images_url* (mind the plural version *remote_**images**_url*) only give me

> undefined method remote_images_url

I also tried *remote_image_url* which would be the default helper in case of single file upload. Also undefined method.

How can I upload remote files when using "multiple files upload" with carrierwave?

Comment: item.remote_image_url = [params[:image_url1], params[:image_url2]]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But as I said remote_image_url also fails with an "undefined method" exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I had a look into the github repository of carrierwave and I found this:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb

Luckily it's all described in the comments in this file. There was only one little thing I had to change. In the comments it says that for a column called *images* I had to use the helper method *remote_image_urls*. But actually I have to use *remote_images_urls* (always plural).

So that's the solution in my case:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :images, ImagesUploader
  serialize :images, JSON
  ...
end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  item.remote_images_urls = [params[:image_url]]
  ...
end
```

Mind the right plural types in the helper method as well as the surrounding array for the params (carrierwave excpects an array).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `item.remote_images_urls` not `item.remote_images_url` and assign the array of remote url. This works for me although CarrierWave rubydoc suggests me to use `item.remote_image_urls` . So, maybe you should try one of these .

For reference [CarrierWave rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave%2FMount%3Amount_uploaders)